# What do I do if two companies approach me about the same subcontract

Tags: subcontracting

I have working relationships with two larger companies. They do deals with other companies, then they pass the work over to me, and I fulfil it as a transparent representative. The client doesn't know I'm a subcontractor.

I was approached this morning by both companies asking me to take on a particular job that they are tendering for. I can tell from the description that it's probably the same job.

At some point in the negotiations I am probably going to have to speak to the end client in person. At this point it will be apparent that it's the same person. This will likely cause embarrassment.

What is the ethical way to handle this?

- Should I tell one company I can't represent them?
- Should I represent the first company who asked me, or the company I prefer to do business with?
- Should I let it ride, attempt to avoid facetime, and just let them fight it out between them? Only one company will get the deal, and I'll be there to pick it up.

Comment: "The client doesn't know I'm a subcontractor."  Would the client care if they knew?  When you do this sort of job, do you keep the fact that you are a subcontractor a secret?

Comment: If the client knew that both companies were actually offering pretty much the exact same service (i.e. me), and they knew that they could actually just have approached me directly for a much cheaper deal, it would be embarassing for everyone, and would likely lead to bad feeling and potentially the loss of the deal.

Comment: I understand the sensitivity of this particular situation, but what about a "normal" job under these circumstances?  Is there an expectation that you will keep your subcontractor status secret?  If so, why?

Comment: @dan1111 - Quite a lot of agencies don't have very many full-time staff, only sales people, yet they give out the impression of being massively capable. They can do this by subcontracting work to smaller companies. Their role is reputation management, client liaison, and sales. The end client is never made aware of the implementation details, only that the work was done and done well. This is relatively common practice as it would be expensive for an agency to keep many skilled employees on in permanent roles.

Comment: Given there appears to be regional differences in the etiquette here, can you add a location tag?

Comment: If it leads to an embarrassing situation with the customer then both agencies are likely to put blame on you and may not use you in the future.  For sure the more expensive agency will not like the situation.

Comment: *Is* this agency work? Are you just being put forward to other companies to work for them? If these "larger companies" are, in fact, recruitment agencies that changes the question and the answers. My assumption is that end-client wants some work done and has asked two intermediaries for quotes to get the work done and will choose one based on the tender responses. What is the situation?

Comment: @superluminary the client company knows that they couldn't just approach you for this job, because (we should assume) they didn't know of you before the meeting. It is the same case as with recruiting agencies. You could cut their fee by contacting the candidates beforehand, but without the agency you'd never meet the candidates in the first place.

Comment: @MarvMills - no, not recruitment agencies. Just regular software agencies. They're not finding a job, they're managing a client and asking my specialist company to do the actual work of fulfilling the brief. The client won't know any different. Most software agencies work like this. It's good for them because they don't need lots of permies for every arbitrary bit of software they may use only occasionally. It's good for my company because we get to specialise in a particular stack and don't have to chase clients. It's good for the client because they don't have to take a chance on an unknown.

Comment: Then I still don't see the issue- your company is a known specialist in certain work. End client engages two agencies to quote on brief, both ask you for your quote- Presumably the agency pays you not the end-client? You give out two quotes. Both are incorporated and subsumed in the agencies' quotes. The end client picks agency they want to work with, that agency engages your company to do the work on the terms you agreed with them. I concede there could be an issue if you were facing off to the end client as part of the tender process, but that's not necessarily the problem you think it is

Comment: Since you got contracted within 10 minutes I bet  both companies read a recent posting.    Don't try and poach any existing customers either of there companies introduced you to but maybe starting scanning postings so you can get more direct jobs.

Comment: Are you typically introduced to clients as an employee of the bidding company or an employee of your niche company?

Comment: @Myles - neither, I would just be introduced. Clients are never interested in those sorts of details.

Comment: @MarvMills - My company is not well known. I don't have the time or budget for big marketing campaigns, and clients are generally not well informed enough to know what to look for. Agencies, on the other hand, have time and budget for reputation management, sales, and client liaison, and can score repeat custom. They have reach. Combine the reach with the specialist know-how and you have something which works.

Comment: @superluminary In my experience (in a totally different industry) where it isn't explicitly stated the assumption would probably be that you are a part of the bidding company.  If that's the case you definitely need to resolve this before the client introduction stage.  Personally I would decline to the company that in your experience is less likely be awarded the contract.

Comment: You aren't going to be the only person these two companies are going to try to place in front of the client.  If you do get presented by both your resume will end up in the trash (if the client has any respect for their agreements with the recruiting firms.)  And as other have pointed out... no one care how many times you've been sub'd before you are in the position.  (I am currently a 4th order sub-contractor and everyone I work with knows.)

Comment: As a note... just ask the companies looking to contract you out.  They know they aren't the own fish in the sea and they don't want to colide on appointments either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I work in pretty similar fashion in Denmark - and the clear expectation here is that you only go with one of them.

I'm assuming the ones you prefer partnering with were not the first to approach you - so it's a bit tricky.

Come clean - tell the least preferred partner that you're suspecting the client/project is similar to the one where you've already opened talks with another party.

-- Edit: Added from comments --

In Denmark, it would be considered the sub-contractor's responsibility to avoid these 'CV collisions' at the client - because only the sub-contractor knows who they've been approached by.

Allowing your CV to be sent more than once to an end-client might trigger a negative response. If the two companies doing the bidding have claimed that their proposed candidate(s) are employees, two identical CVs could make the client reject the person immediately. This is at least the argument made in Denmark for why one must avoid forwarding a CV through multiple channels.

Comment: This is the case, and yes, my least preferred partner approached me about 10 minutes before my more preferred partner. They are least preferred because they have 60 day payment terms, as opposed to 3 day payment terms from my other contact.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, and I agree that it is ok to pick the preferred partner, as long as you haven't made a commitment or gotten started for the least preferred one.

Comment: OK. I would fix this today. Since the gap is only 10 minutes, you could plausibly claim that the preferred partner simply beat them to it. And since you were busy or the project descriptions were a bit different, you have only just now realized that the project might be the same.

Comment: Why not say "Sorry, I was also approached today by another client about what looks like the same project, and they offer me better terms."  It is honest, and perhaps you could negotiate a better deal with the company out of it.

Comment: @superluminary Did they contact you by phone or by email? If it's email, you can claim that you essentially received them at the same time.

Comment: @DavidK - Phone, but I tend not to lie about things anyway.

Comment: @dan1111 Honesty could also work. Personally, I usually choose to 'weasel' out in order to not risk permanently antagonizing the gatekeepers

Comment: @dan1111 In this case, I'm gonna agree with you. The difference in payment terms is so massive, that honesty should be the way to go. Whoever was 'first' pales in significance with waiting 2 months for payment

Comment: I would go with the better payment terms.

Comment: "If the client found out the truth they wouldn't do the deal. This is the argument made in Denmark for not doing anything that risks the client finding out the truth" -- I don't know the situation in law, but this sounds rather as if the deal crucially relies on a very specific deception, regarding a lie told to the client about the employment status of the OP, and therefore might be fraudulent. "Don't get caught defrauding your clients" is a rule everywhere, not just Denmark ;-)

Comment: A 10 minute difference is effectively a tie.

Comment: ... one hopes that in the OP's case the main contractors haven't "claimed that their proposed candidate(s) are employees", but perhaps have allowed the client to assume that.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Due to the negative comments this answer has received I want to clarify my assumptions about the situation, which are:

1. The end client is attempting to secure a third party to develop something and they have approached two (or more) agencies with a brief for which two (or more) are tendering quotes
2. Two of the agencies contacted, knowing they cannot personally deliver all the work required have sought quotes from the OP for part or all of the work
3. The end-client doesn't care which individuals deliver the work, they contract with the agency to sort that out for them.
4. The agencies are contracted to and paid by the end-client
5. The OP is contracted to and paid by the agency
6. The agencies are not trying to "place" the OP at the end-client in any way, they are merely contracting the OP to undertake some work they are doing (which happens to be for a third party, the end-client)
7. The OP's question was not about CV-clash, or the agencies misleading the end-client by suggesting the OP was an employee, or protecting the agencies or the end-client, it was, as stated, about the potential embarrassment felt when/if they find out two of the agencies they are working with both want to use the same third-party, the OP, to fulfil all or part of the work.

If these assumptions are false then I accept this answer is not a good one, but until the OP clarifies what the situation is, these assumptions are equally valid.

**Answer**

The relationship between your client and *their* clients is not your responsibility. Irrespective of what you have deduced, all you should do is respond to each of your clients separately (and probably with the same quote!) and let them deal with the tendering process to their prospective clients. It  is a risk they take when subcontracting into an open market. I don't see how it would reflect badly on you.

Also, don't be tempted to tell both of your clients that you have been approached by another company in the same tendering process- that is probably breaching confidentiality.

Comment: True, but making my clients look awesome *is* my responsibility.

Comment: @superluminary ...and you will be able to do that irrespective of who gets picked :)

Comment: In Denmark, it would be considered the sub-contractor's responsibility to avoid these 'CV collisions' at the client - because only the sub-contractor knows who they've been approached by

Comment: @morsor Two independent companies are seeking to sell the OP's services on- it just so happens they are both targeting the same end client. Suppose the OP manufactured furniture, would they only want their goods to be sold on by one of the intermediaries or would they seek to maximise their chance of doing business by allowing both intermediaries to sell their goods? I see no difference.

Comment: @Marv Mills Allowing your CV to be sent more than once to an end-client might trigger a negative response. If the two companies doing the bidding have claimed that their proposed candidate(s) are employees, two identical CVs could make the client reject the person immediately. This is at least the argument made in Denmark for why one must avoid forwarding a CV through multiple channels

Comment: @Marv Mills As a sub-contractor, you may off course deal with multiple companies and even have them engage in a bidding war - but when the dust settles, you only go forward with one of them

Comment: @MarvMills, I would agree with you if the OP were merely providing a service to the intermediate company, who passed it on. But if they are dealing with the end client directly then they are acting on behalf of the company in the negotiations, and I think that creates an expectation they would not do something to jeopardize those negotiations--such as participating in a competing proposal.

Comment: @MarvMills - the difference is that the service is rebranded. If two companies were selling furniture for different prices in different boxes with different brand names, and it became apparent late in the negotiations that actually the furniture was exactly the same, I would expect some head-scratching from the client, probably some social media comments, and perhaps a loss of future business.

Comment: @MarvMills - I would also expect the client to migrate away from the more expensive, more highly regarded provider towards the cheaper, less well-regarded provider.

Comment: The fault lies with the companies misrepresenting an associate subcontractor as their own employee, not with the OP seeking to do business. My point is that it is not the OP's responsibility to manage fallout from *their* misrepresentation. Clearly there are regional differences to the sensitivity over this. In my experience the UK marketplace is not so sensitive to this kind of thing. YMMV.

Comment: Maybe not his responsibility but the fallout could come on the OP.  If the more expensive company is made to look bad then they may not use the OP in the future.   If both companies are embarrassed when if it comes out then both may chose not to use the OP in the future.

Comment: I agree that a quote should be prepared but not so sure about the "fight it out" mentality. Both companies should know that OP will work for other companies *including* competitors (or they are incredibly naive...) Having them fight it out hurts OP in the long run.

Comment: @MarvMills: you say it's not the OP's responsibility to manage their misrepresentation, but since he enthusiastically participates in it, I rather think that it's also his misrepresentation and therefore also his responsibility. So the question still stands what to do next (and the OP's first option avoids risk of embarrassment, at least on this job, so there's a route to avoid getting caught). In your furniture analogy: he's already agreed to put two different retailers' logos on identical products, *and* agreed not to undermine the notion that these are "their" products.

Comment: -1 This advice pushes a potentially uncomfortable situation further towards its logical conclusion (that the truth surfaces in a meeting with the end-client). It's dangerous advice, and could be professionally damaging for the OP.

Comment: Oh dear. This is a standard and common business model. There is nothing shady, underhand or *dangerous* going on here. An intermediary is back-to-backing contracts with subcontractors to deliver work to their client. The OP is lucky- two of them want to use him. That doubles his chances of getting the work. I am struggling to understand why anyone would think the end-client will be in the slightest bit interested- their contract will be with the intermediary. Anyhow, this seems to have stirred up a lot of passion, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: However before I go, let's clear one thing up- are the intermediaries sending the OPs CV to its clients? That seems the root of a lot of confusion. My assumption for my answers is that they are not; they are merely providing a service to their clients and using the OP to fulfil that service..

Comment: You're the one who chose to call it "misrepresentation", that would make it underhand if not shady or dangerous. Anyway, the questioner's comments elsewhere have made it clear that the agencies aren't misrepresenting his employment status or the fact that they're subcontracting. Fortunately the client doesn't care about that, just doesn't want to face Hobson's Choice of the same subcontractor by different routes. And that is something the questioner wishes to co-operate with the agencies in preventing. Quoting them both and letting them proceed has a high chance of not achieving that.

Comment: My use of misrepresentation was in reference to the possibility that the agencies are claiming that the OP is their employee. It is now reasonably clear that is not the case. If the agency is indeed selling the OP on as a contractor to the third party I would totally agree there is an issue here- but nothing about this suggests that, only that the agencies happen to be approaching the same subcontractor to do *their* work. And there is nothing whatsoever unusual in that.

Answer (score 5):

If I were you, I would pick one of the companies and tell the other one that you have already been approached for the same job and you are in the process of putting a quote together for them and it would not be ethical for you to work on the same contract from two different angles.

Who you choose is totally up to you. If both of them are willing to pay the same ballpark figure for compensation, choose the one which you feel more comfortable doing business with. If one company pays significantly better and you need that money, choose them. Just don't make them duke it out for compensation. It will definitely blow up in your face and you may not even get the job from either of them.

Being upfront and honest is the best policy for your continued success and ongoing relationship with both of these companies.

This is my take and I know it is subjective.

Answer (score 2):

You have two possible scenarios here:

1) Both companies are vying for the same contract.

2) Both companies are working similar contracts for different companies.

It's in your best interest to figure out which is correct. I'm assuming you have a good working relationship with both companies. As such, why not just ask them who the contracts are for? Stating that you may have a potential conflict. If it's the same contract, use that to your advantage and pit both companies against each other in order to get a higher bill rate and better payment terms. If the contracts are for different companies but similar deliverables then negotiate a fixed price contract with both and essentially kill two birds with one stone. Double the money, same amount of work.

Comment: It is almost definitely the former. I suspect pitting my contacts against one another might not go down so well :)

Comment: There may be 3) one of the companies is a subcontractor of another, so that OP is in a choice of being either a subcontractor or a subsubcontractor. In such case it may be even more embarassing to meet the "client".

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe this, two companies asked you if you would accept to do work for them as a subcontractor - which will happen. You figured out that the actual work to be done is exactly the same.

It seems then that neither company actually has the deal yet (they can't if it's the same deal). So if in theory you said "yes" to both, then you would expect one letter saying "great, you are starting tomorrow" and one letter saying "sorry, the deal fell through". So no harm would be done to the company that loses. Also in theory if you say "yes" to one and "no" to the other, and the other company wins the deal, you lose out.

What would you do if you knew there are two different jobs, at the same time, so you can't do them both, and both still in the tendering process, so if they both win their tender, you would have to let one company down? Best would be in that case to tell them each that you have not accepted any other offer, that you would gladly do the job for them, but that there is another very similar offer, and you would sign a binding contract with the first one who offers it.

And that is what they can tell them in this case as well. Except you can tell them you believe the other offer is for the identical job, so you would expect eventually to be offered one contract only.

If you visit the company where the work would be done before the end of the tender, it would be best to tell them what the situation is, recommend both tendering companies, and let them make their decision. If they are happy with you, their decision might be to go with the cheaper tender (since they get the same person doing the work), or with the person who sent you to them first.